# gota Dataframe: How to delete a row by index?

Tags: csv, go, gota

Suppose I read a csv file using gota's dataframe.ReadCSV; how can I remove the ith row from this dataframe? The documentation has a function for dropping columns but not rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select:

```golang
   // df := dataframe.ReadCSV(/*your io variable*/)
   // I use this example
   df := dataframe.LoadRecords(
        [][]string{
            []string{"A", "B", "C", "D"},
            []string{"a", "4", "5.1", "true"},
            []string{"k", "5", "7.0", "true"},
            []string{"k", "4", "6.0", "true"},
            []string{"a", "2", "7.1", "false"},
        },
    )

    fmt.Println("Original dataframe:")
    fmt.Println(df)
    
    // only select A, B, C
    // and update df
    df = df.Select([]int{0, 1, 2}) // []string{"A", "B", "C",}

    fmt.Println("Updated dataframe:")
    fmt.Println(df)
```

Note: if you can, Don't use this package, because this pkg not have support!

Github repo tells this:
`This is an implementation of DataFrames, Series and data wrangling methods for the Go programming language. The API is still in flux so use at your own risk.`

Better way is use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) in python!